# How to deserialize an object in c# containing stack?

Tags: c#, json

I serialize an object by JsonConvert.SerializeObject and then deserilize by JsonConvert.DeserializeObject, I have a stack in serialized object, the problem i'm facing is when I deserilize the serialized object, the  stack that I get is  in reversed order that is when I pop an element, instead of returning the recently pushed element, it returns first pushed element. How to overcome this problem?

Comment: one workaround would be to first reverse the stack and then serialize it. then after deserializing it should be normal again

Comment: please share some example and code snippets you are using. that would be more helpful